# Checking if a document contains a key (Firestore)using dart- flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to check in a document of type DocumentSnapshot contain a key (Field in firestore).  but the code below shows an error.

```
final snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("xxx")
        .where("xxx", isEqualTo: xxx)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        if (doc.containsKey('CodeLink') == true) {//HERE IS THE ERROR
          //xxxx
        }
        else{
          //xxx
        }
     });     
});
```

I am expecting to know how to check in a document contains a specific key or not

Answer (score 0):

Your `doc` variable is a `DocumentSnapshot`. If you check that documentation you'll see that it indeed doesn't have a `containsKey` method, which explains the error message.

If you want to check whether the data has a specific field, you're looking for:

```
doc.data()!.containsKey('CodeLink')
```

Comment: this still shows an error message which is (The method 'containsKey' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.) I tried using the (!) operator but it did not work

Comment: "it didn't work" is really hard to help with. Also: did you check what `doc.data()!` gives you when you set a breakpoint on this line and run the code in a debugger?